# django : Failed to save object in database

Tags: python, django

First of all I should mention that I'm new to Python as well as Django.

i tried to follow instruction from [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html)

my models.py contains following :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

then, when i tried to save it with `board.save()`, this error messages appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: board_board.name

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rierii/Applications/ProjectPython/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: board_board.name
```

i need help with this error and have no idea why it appears...

Comment: What did you try to save, show us https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

as it is telling you, it failed to pass UNIQUE constraint, it means, you didn't enter a unique name for board.

> UNIQUE constraint failed: board_board.name

Answer (score 0):

The error shows because your name in `board` is **unique**. So, while you are saving new object, as the `name` **matches**. Django throws that error. So, to handle this you have to change your `views.py`